# OpenCV - where are cv.h, core.hpp, highgui.hpp and other file includes?

Tags: windows, opencv

Most every sample piece of code in OpenCV starts with these lines (or something similar):

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

And yet, these files are not in the opencv installation package?  I've installed opencv several times and cannot find these files on my computer.  What's going on?  How can something so fundamental be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, they are often within the `build/include/opencv` directory.

Comment: You, Sir, Are correct.  For whatever reason, searching for the files in win7 and copernic desktop search did not show them.  Thank you!